# Terraform cloud : Import existing resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-cloud

I am using **terraform cloud** to manage the state of the infrastructure provisioned in AWS.

I am trying to use `terraform import` to import an existing resource that is currently not managed by terraform.

I understand `terraform import` is a local only command. I have set up a workspace reference as follows:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.12.0"

  backend "remote" {
    hostname = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "foo"

    workspaces {
      name = "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

The AWS credentials are configured in the remote cloud workspace but terraform does not appear to be referencing the AWS credentials from the workspace but instead falls back trying to using the local credentials which points to a different AWS account. I would like Terraform to use the credentials by referencing the variables in the workspace when I run `terraform import`.

When I comment out the locally configured credentials, I get the error:

```
Error: No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.
```

I would have expected terraform to use the credentials configured in the workspace.

Note that terraform is able to use the credentials correctly, when I run the plan/apply command directly from the cloud console.

Answer (score 3):

Per the backends section of the [import docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/index.html#remote-backends), `plan` and `apply` run in Terraform Cloud whereas `import` runs locally.  Therefore, the import command will not have access to workspace credentials set in Terraform Cloud.  From the docs:

> In order to use Terraform import with a remote state backend, you may need to set local variables equivalent to the remote workspace variables.

So instead of running the following locally (assuming you've provided access keys to Terraform Cloud):

```sh
terraform import aws_instance.myserver i-12345
```

we should run for example:

```sh
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=abc
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=1234
terraform import aws_instance.myserver i-12345
```

where the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` have the same permissions as those configured in Terraform Cloud.

### Note for AWS SSO users

If you are using AWS SSO and CLI v2, functionality for terraform to be able to use the credential cache for sso was added per [this AWS provider issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/10851).  The steps for importing with an SSO profile are:

- Ensure you've performed a login and have an active session with e.g. `aws sso login --profile my-profile`
- Make the profile name available to terraform as an environment variable with e.g. `AWS_PROFILE=my-profile terraform import aws_instance.myserver i-12345`

If the following error is displayed, ensure you are [using a version of the cli > 2.1.23](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17372):

```
Error: SSOProviderInvalidToken: the SSO session has expired or is invalid
│ caused by: expected RFC3339 timestamp: parsing time "2021-07-18T23:10:46UTC" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "UTC" as "Z07:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the data provider, for Example:-

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "test" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = "BUCKET_NAME"
    key    = "BUCKET_KEY WHERE YOUR TERRAFORM.TFSTATE FILE IS PRESENT"
    region = "CLOUD REGION"
  }
}
```

Now you can call your provisioned resources
Example :-

For getting the VPC ID:-

```
data.terraform_remote_state.test.*.outputs.vpc_id
```

Just make the cloud resource property you want to refer should be in exported as output and stored in terraform.tfstate file

Comment: I am trying to import an existing resource that is not managed by terraform. terraform_remote_state will not help in this situation.

Comment: try - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer#use-with-aws

Comment: Generating terraform files from exisitng infrastructure is not the concern. I have the resource already identified. My main challenge is that ```terraform import``` does not appear to be referencing cloud workspace variables and instead is using local variables for the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Since Terraform **v1.5.0** you can use an [`import` block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import#syntax):

```
import {
  to = some_resource_type.some_name
  id = "external_id_to_be_imported"
}

resource "some_resource_type" "some_name" {
  name = "foo"
  # (other resource arguments...)
}
```

Beginning in **v1.6.0** you can use variable interpolation within `import` but the values must be literals in earlier 1.5.x versions.

Once the resource has been imported, the relevant `import` block is subsequently ignored and can be removed.